# Enumerate with no top-level item

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to create a list such as

```
1  i) Item text
  ii) Item text
 iii) Item text
  iv) Item text
```

In other words: right-aligned item numbers, and no top-level item. The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
%   \item 0 0
    \begin{enumerate}[i)]
        \item 1 0
        \item 1 1
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

raises an error: `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` which is resolved by uncommenting the item above.

Comment: You can use `\item\begin{enumerate}[i)]` to achieve the desired numbering.

Comment: I thought I had tried this! Thank you. Another issue is that environments (e.g. `flalign`) don't start on the same line as the item number. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: You need to put display math into a minipage {\linewidth}.

Comment: For example: `\item\begin{flalign}y&=x^2&&\\x&=\sqrt{y}\end{flalign}` renders as `1. \\ y=x² \\ x=√y` (I don't want the first newline.)